# draw circle and inject letters in which android

Tags: android, colors, geometry

[Like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OdYgf.png)

Hello, I am trying to develop an android app
I want to create a circle and inject the first letter of the user's name in this circle, like the picture. how I can do this and how I can change the color dynamically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can draw a circle using canvas and paint

```
Paint paint = new Paint(); 
Canvas canvas = new Canvas();
canvas.drawCircle(10, 10, 50, paint);
```

50 is the radius of the circle .

In your case you want draw a letter inside the circle for that do this

```
    //Add this to your above code.

   paint.setColor(Color.BLACK); //You can change it to any color you want.
paint.setTextSize(16); 
canvas.drawText("Username First letter goes here", x, y, paint);
```

ThankYou I hope this was helpfull.

Comment: and how I can inject this circle in the layout.

Comment: You have to create a custom View

Comment: thanks, i will try this nchallah.